# Poisson rv determining sample size of normally distributed rv's

Tags: normal-distribution, expectation, poisson-distribution, variance

[image]

In the above problem, I understand that the Poisson random variable determines the sample size corresponding to Y. But I'm not sure about how to approach the problem.

If the problem didn't involve the poisson random variable, I could find the moment-generating function of the sum of i.i.d normally distributed random variables and find the first two moments to find the variance. But how does this problem change with the introduction of the poisson random variable? Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:$$Y=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N X_i}{N}$$

By law of total variance,

$$\operatorname{Var}(Y)=\mathbb{E}(\operatorname{Var}(Y|N))+\operatorname{Var}(\mathbb{E}(Y|N))$$

$$\operatorname{Var}(\mathbb{E}(Y|N))=\operatorname{Var}(\mu)=0$$

Hence you just have to evaluate:
$$\mathbb{E}(\operatorname{Var}(Y|N))$$

Edit:

When $N=0$, $Y=0, \operatorname{Var}(Y|N=0)=0$

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{Var}(Y|N)]&=\sigma^2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \frac{\exp(-\lambda)\lambda^n}{n!}
\end{align}

Comment: Hmm is this right?

Doing the variance, you can factor out $\frac{1}{N^2}$ and then the variance becomes (sigma^2)/(N^2) and taking the expected value of that (where N is a poisson random variable) would be (sigma^2)/(λ^2)? (Sorry I'm really bad at MathJax)

Comment: don't forget the sum which contribute a factor of $N$ in the numerator. I get $\sigma^2 \mathbb{E}\left[ \frac1N\right]$, it is unclear to me how to simplify this.

Comment: Hmm here (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80874/expectation-of-reciprocal-of-a-variable) it suggests to use the law of the unconscious statistician but not sure if that can apply here

Comment: I don't see how to simplify the sum. though it converges by comparison test.

Comment: Could you explain your newest edit? I recognize the pdf of the poisson distribution there but confused about how you simplified E(1/N) to that and where the 1/n came from

Comment: When $N=0$, we have $Y=0$. Otherwise given $N$, the variance is $\frac{\sigma^2}{N}$. hence the expression on the right is just $\sum_{i=1}^n Var(Y|N)P(N=n)$.

Comment: ah gotcha. Makes sense. Thanks!